# Let .Net framework be Localization

Tags: deployment, installation, setup-deployment

I add .Net framework to the deploying to be requirement, but when I try to setup my software, it is Chinese in the explanation(Maybe is I'm in Taiwan). Like the picture:
[image]

I want the explanation (like the area of red eclipse in the picture) to be English( although the agent is Japanese, they want it is English)

How can I do?
Or what's the keyword about the question?

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the method!

My .Net is Visual Studio 10,
And try to change the file of eula.rtf by:

C://Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/v7.0A/Bootstrapper/Packages/DotNetFX35SP1/(your local document like "zh-Hant" for me)

And my .Net framework is 3.5 SP1, so I change the files in DotNetFX35SP1.

My eula.rtf is Chinese original, so I try to change it to English(In DotNetFX4.0, there is several language of the eula.rtf file)

So I fix it!